# Array with values from another array

Tags: javascript

How can I obtain something like this:

```
items = [{
  value: 'All',
  checked: false
}, {
  value: 'a',
  checked: false
}, {
  value: 'b',
  checked: false
}, {
  value: 'c',
  checked: false
}];

eg.: console.log(items[2].value)='b'
```

where 'a', 'b', 'c' .. come from an array `arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ...]`

I tried with a for

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    items=[
        {value: 'All', checked: false},
        {value: arr[i], checked: false}
    ]
}
```

but this is not working and I have no other idea. Is there another way to obtain this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You're adding the `All` property in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = ['all', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const result = arr.map(value => ({ value, checked: false }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

```
var items = [{value: 'All', checked: false}];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    items.push({value: arr[i], checked: false})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like this that you seek ?

```js
const arr = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
];

const final = [{
    value: 'All',
    checked: false,
  },

  ...arr.map(x => ({
    value: x,
    checked: false,
  })),
];

console.log(final);
```